# C++/CLI windows label form

Tags: windows, c++-cli

I need help getting `label1` to display the string that the user inputs.

I know that std::string and System::string are two different types, so I casted the inputted string to `String^`.

The textbox:

```
private: System::Void text_box_1(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
                 cin >> name; 
                 String^ something = gcnew String(name.c_str());
                 label1->Text = "Name->" + something;
```

Function that returns string:

```
string getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
```

The problem is, `label1` always outputs "Name-> `blank`". 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That code makes no sense whatsoever.  Do **not** use `std::cin` in a GUI app, it is only valid in console mode apps.  You already have a String^, it is the Text property of the TextBox.  This looks like a very poorly named event handler for the TextBox::TextChanged event, so it is just a one-liner: `label1->Text = textBox1->Text;`  Find a decent tutorial or book on Winforms programming, you don't have the right instincts yet.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks. It's pretty evident I'm new to Windows programming. Any recommendations as to which book/tutorial I should study from? I'm pretty much using my Google Fu right now.